# I want to know the place of publicationa and publisher name

Tags: ownership, search

In reference to the patent: [US4464123](https://www.google.com/patents/US4464123)

Comment: It's a US patent. Are you asking who owns it?

Answer (score 1):

Any patent application information for a US patent can be obtained from this link ([USPTO](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair)). The information retrieval is pretty simple and I'll walk you through it so you can do it yourself here forth. I feel that the question I'm addressing here is generic and It would be great if this answer is linked for future questions regarding USPTO information retrieval. I'll try to make it as elaborate as I can so it's easy for anyone to obtain the required information. Click the link and lets get started.

1.As soon as you're on the site you will be asked to verify that you're a human being with the help of a captcha code. Go ahead and verify your existence.

2.Next, you will be asked to fill in the reference number of your document to retrieve the relevant information. Here you'll have to choose the right column to enter your document number.

These are the options:

- Application Number (If you have the application number)
- Control Number (If you have the control number provided by USPTO)
- Patent Number (If the patent is granted)
- PCT Number (If you have thePCT application number)
- Publication Number (If the patent is an application)
- International Design Registration Number (If it's a US design reference)

3.Choose the relevant column and fill in the details. Remember to remove the **kind code** when you enter the number. Kind codes are the prefixes to the reference number. For eg. For the document under question US4464123, remove US and enter **4464123** in the patent column as the document is granted. It should take you to the Patent Application Information Retrieval page.

4.Here in the application data tab you'll find all the relevant information you need. While you're here you can choose the Assignments tab and see all the assignments of the document under question.

There you go, you have your information. I'm gonna go ahead and answer your question but I would recommend you to confirm my answer by cross checking it on the USPTO site.

The document under question is a US patent document and hence its place of publication is United States. And I'm assuming you mean the **applicant's** name when you talk about publishers name and for the document under question it is WAYNE GLOVER , ODESSA, FL (US).

Hope this helped!